# DirectShow Read From Memory with a Callback method

Tags: c++, video, callback, directshow, playback

Until now I used MCI & mmioInstallIOProc for video playback with the help of the mentioned callback method for reading data chunks directly from memory.

Is there any sample that accomplish the same playback method using DirectShow ? I played a little bit, with the "MemFile" example that is included in the Platform SDK but this code reads the whole file to the memory while I need to load chunks of data instead.

Where to look or what interface to use to accomplish the goal ?

Regards,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just created a new source filter !

Comment: Answers on StackOverflow are supposed to bring relevant details about the solution, so that others could benefit from both Q and A.

Comment: Yes you have right, but the problem of this questions is a kind of strange since I wanted to decrypt my data before I send them to the video renderer. The source filter I created its almost identical with the one you can find in the SDK, except the code I added, that  processes the bunch of data are read by calling the decrypter code, and then they follow the normal way. !

Answer (score 2):

The memfile sample is the right one. You need to implement the IAsyncReader interface to pull data from your memory buffers, and that is the closest sample.

Comment: Hi, 

In the included file "asyncrdr.h", the class "CAsyncOutputPin" is already a "IAsyncReader" subclass. In any way is there a callback mechanism inside the IAsyncReader interface cos MSDN on that topic does not mention anything.

Comment: In the memfile sample, in CAsyncOutputPin, replace the calls to m_pIO with calls to your class that will fetch the data. If you're after a way to call into the output pin to deliver data, you will need to queue data and pull it from the output pin instead.

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure that I really understand the solution you purpose. How can my callback function notified that the downstream needs data to feed ? Can you explain that to me ?